# Does the ''afectar'' need to use with the article "a"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Puzzling! Why he added "a" behind "afectar"?

Desde un libro llamado"西班牙语专四高频词汇快速突破1000题" de China.

> Aunque esté ocurriendo en los Estados Unidos, también podría afectar a Europa.

Comment: Chinese? Really?

Comment: Sí, soy Chino.Esta oración se origina de un libro de ejercicio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fundéu says](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/afectar-afectar-a-formas-validas/):

> ***Afectar***, como otros verbos que significan daño o provecho, **admiten la construcción con *a*** delante de objetos directos de persona o de cosa

So the verb *afectar* is an exception to the usual rule that transitive verbs use "a" when the direct object is a person and no "a" when it is a thing. In the case of *afectar*, using "a" for all direct objects (persons or things) is **correct**, and is the most common usage in Spain. In Latin America, omitting "a" for things seems to be more common.